# How to make for loop with $1 - 1 cycles

Tags: sed, for

I am trying to make sh script which uses 'sed' to make bubblesort algorithm

I am strugling, how to make for loop

```
for n in $1
do
   echo $n
done
```

How can I change body of the for loop to make just `n-1` cycles? I tried this `$1-1` but it doesn't work. It will print part of the string and - 1.

Comment: show `$1` value

Comment: "1 2 3 4 12 56"

Comment: Which *shell* are you using? if it supports arrays - use one e.g. (bash) `list=(1 2 3 4 12 56) ; for ((i=0; i<${#list[@]}-1; i++)); do echo "${list[i]}"; done`

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add important details rather than post them in comments which may not be read. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*n-1 cycles* means that the last item shouldn't be considered.

Use the following approach(assuming that your input argument will always be a string of space-delimited substrings):

```
s=$1

for n in ${s:0:-2}
do 
    echo $n 
done
```

---

`${s:0:-2}` - slice of items containing all items except the last one

```
    ^  ^
    |  | 
  from to
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 
`for i in "$@" ; do echo $i ; done`

You don't need to quote $1, it's not necessary.

Edit: I misunderstood. If you wish to print $1-1, `echo $(( $i-1 ))`
If you are trying to iterate i-1 times, use a modification of this:

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))
{
  echo $x
}
```

Please post your 'bubblesort' script in full, or clarify your question.